# Hp pavilion, windows 10. I replaced the mouse sprite but every time I use the touchscreen, my pointer sprite disappears.

Tags: windows-10, mouse, image-sprites

So the other day, I was messing with mouse sprites, and replaced my pointer sprite. Now, whenever I use touchscreen it just disappears. The other sprites show up fine, so that I know that my mouse didn't completely break.
Is there any way to fix this?
sprites that I used are here: https://www.mediafire.com/?zhn6t544881zsj9

Comment: The mouse cursor usually disappears when I use the touchscreen on the several devices I've used with touchscreens. What happens when you use the default mouse cursor?

Comment: The default cursor is normal and has normal behavior (basically, it doesn't disappear every time I use the touchscreen.)